# Can you call a widget from a filter class

Tags: php, yii

Sorry if this is a dumb question but im creating a filter class that watches for events and generates e-mails on those events. One of my requirements is that it add a table of data to the e-mail. 
Two relateed questions.

1 - is it possible to call `$this->widget('zii::widgets.grid.CGridView, array());` from a function within the filter.

2 - Is it possible to send the results of the widget to a variable to be included in the body of an e-mail?

If this isn't possible i will start work on exporting to an Excel file that can be attached to the e-mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put this wrong. Indifferently where you are, to render you need a controller.

So you have to create and instantiate a controller to be able to call the renderPartial on it. So what I would do is that I would put all the look into an EmailController and simply initialize and use the renderPartial, last parameter to return the output.

We used PHPMailer and the line looks like this:

```
$mail->Body = CController::renderInternal(Yii::app()->basePath . '/views/email/email_report.php', array('arrData' => $arrData), true);
```

we event' dont have an EmailController. (the above code is called from a console app).